# IE 10 Download Acceptance Bar

Tags: internet-explorer

Can anyone tell me the difference between this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

I'm using IE 10. I'm getting them both when redirecting a page to a UNC path.

The page that redirects to the UNC path is being launched from a modal window. This means that when the first version opens the user can't actually download the file as you can't click on the bar. The second version works fine.

It's got to be something to do with the file type.

Anyone point me in the direction of some documentation?